# How to save the state of page (colors, background color of each element)

Tags: jquery, css

In my page i have a button to change the color of text and background

```
 $("#invert_color_button").click(function () {

     $("body *").not("#text-resize-buttons *").css("cssText", "background-color: black; color: white;");
});
```

how can i save the original values and revert them with another button?

Comment: By saving them to global variable

Comment: can you give me a hint on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't use inline CSS changes in JS. Instead use some classes eg:

```
.selected {
    background: red;
}

.deselected {
    background: gray;
}
```

And then detect if DIV has a class and swap them. You can also use data atributes for this.

Comment: where should i declare those classe's?

Comment: In your css file. Initially you add lets say .deselected class to elements and using JS you swap these classes.